# Cassandra vs HDFS Compression ratio

Tags: cassandra, compression, hdfs

I do an evaluation on HDFS and Cassandra's storage amount using the same input data in a single machine. Both HDFS and Cassandra has only 1 replica.
My input data are binary bytes, in total 31M. It turned out to be HDFS has less data than Cassandra.

1. HDFS : 16.4 M. (use COMPRESS.BLOCK strategy)(
2. Cassandra: 50M. (use CQL interface, with default setting(e.g. compression))

   How could that be possible, since Cassandra use columnar storage ?

   Is there anyone could help me figure it out? Thanks very much.

   My Cassandra version is 2.1.9.

Comment: Here is my  input data's schema:  10 fields are in long type,  2 fields are in string type.   As in Cassandra CQL, there are 9 fields in bigint, 2 fields in text, 1 field in timestamp

Answer (score 2):

You will see better C* disk usage if using 3.+. its a 2.1 thing that requires the column name along with each field, so if you have 10 fields it will be a lot worse. 3.x is a lot better as it doesnt store redundant data.

HDFS and C* are two completely different things for solving different kinds of problems. If your looking just for most efficient use in disk space then hdfs is probably what you want, as it can store bulk binary data much more efficiently. If your looking for faster reads/writes, C* *may* be a better choice. C* adds to your data to organize and make queries more efficient and to provide guarantees about the data (for consistency). Compression will earn some of that back but in a lot of cases its gonna take up more space than just your raw data would.

Comment: Thanks for your help.And I have some problems with Cassandra read/write rate. May be the rate will be improved if I use C* 3.+. However, do you think it's normal for C* 2.1 to have a write rate which is less than 1M/s (about 3k inserts/s)  under situation above? I use datastax java driver. And I am sure all data are reserved in Memtable, not flushed into SSTable. What'more, commitlog sync is in "period" mode, and I set the period to be longer than the time which insertion requires.

Comment: As for read rate, I find that more processors/threads won't accelerate the read speed, it costs the same time as one single processor needs. In my case, if data are cached, the read rate could get to 180M/s. But when data aren't cached, it goes down to approximately 18M/s. I use HDD, and C* 2.1. Could you please give me some suggestions? Thanks very much.